# How can I get information(coordinate and rgb) about a certain point clicked by mouse on an image? I am using Qt

Tags: image, qt, user-interface

I was able to get the information about the image first(width and height), and next, I want to get the coordinate about certain point on the image and record the information by a mouse click. How can I do that? I am using Qt.

Thanks !

Comment: Please show us the code you are working with so far. There are many different approaches and very little might be applicable depending on your implementation

Answer (score 0):

1 - map the click coordinates to the image coordinates, that will give you the position you clicked on the image.

2 - after that you can use `QImage::pixel(x,y)` to get the RGB value for the pixel at that coordinate.

Comment: what do you mean by map the click coordinates to image coordinates? Is there any calculation I should do to achieve that?

Comment: @yqwang - you are off to a really bad start with programming if you wait for others to solve every simple problem. Try thinking and researching things yourself, it is not that hard, and this way you will learn to solve your problems without having to wait on others.